# How to exclude filetypes when getting latest in Perforce

Tags: perforce, getlatest

When I get latest revision on a folder it gets all files in that folder.
How can I get all files except files with the extension ".ztl" ?

Adding this extension to the p4ignore.ini blocks the submit of them but not the get latest.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude them from your client view.  E.g.:

```
//depot/... //client/...
-//depot/....ztl //client/....ztl
```

Those files are now no longer considered part of your workspace at all -- files matching that depot path will not be synced, and files you add to your workspace matching that path will not be added.